# Bash - echoing variable value in while loop

Tags: bash

This one is probably pretty simple.  I've got a simple while loop which asks the user to input data

```
while [ $i -le $numMasterNodes ]; do
    echo "Enter hostname #$i: "
    read masterHost$i
    ((i+=1))
done
```

I'm trying to get the value of `$masterHost$i` in my loop, for example

```
while [ $i -le $numMasterNodes ]; do
    echo "Enter hostname #$i: "
    read masterHost$i
    echo $masterHost$i
    ((i+=1))
done
```

However, it just returns `1 2 3`, etc... How can I get the value of `$masterHost$i` so I can add it to an array?

Thanks!

Comment: if masterhost is ="5" and $i="3"..you want to echo "53"...?..

Comment: @chepner The question is quite probably a duplicate of something, but my take on it was that OP wanted/needed an ordinary array and didn't know how to [or didn't feel he could use it in the loop] so he tried to "simulate" it, but didn't really want a dynamic variable since he said his end goal was to the data into an array, as per my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably would be happier with an array.  See http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_10_02.html

Note if you already know about arrays, I'm not sure why you're not just using one directly in your loop.

Here's your example recoded to do that:

```
#!/bin/bash -

i=1
numMasterNodes=3

declare -a masterHost

while [ $i -le $numMasterNodes ]; do
    echo "Enter hostname #$i: "
    read masterHost[$i]
    echo ECHO ${masterHost[$i]}
    ((i+=1))
done
```

Comment: Might want an echo -n on the first one to avoid the line break.

Comment: @Eduardo Seems to work fine without.  It's just debug AFAICT

Comment: Of course it works fine, the -n is just to avoid breaking the line when asking for the password.

Comment: thank you!  I thin an array is better, as you mentioned.

Comment: @Eduardo Oh, okay, I see.  You're talking about the _prompt_ [for hostname].  Yeah, I'd do it that way, too.  But, here, I chose to take the minimalist route and just fix the basic problem.  For other questions [particularly in C], if OP's code is far enough off the mark, I'll even do a full [gratuitous] style cleanup.  Herein, style could also include simplifying repetitive constructs or refactoring. Sometimes, it's _really_ necessary, and usually most OPs really appreciate it.  I usually make the decision on a case-by-case basis as to how much extra cleanup to do

Comment: @cookandy You're welcome! The construct you were using reminded me of when [a _long_ time ago] I tried to do something similar.  I was in my first few days of shell programming [csh] and I hadn't yet learned about arrays [IIRC, I knew about csh's `argv` but didn't know I could do `set myary=()`, etc.]